# How to write text on a path in photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, text-on-path

Well, the question isn't exactly what it looks like. Now I have a circular path, and text written on it. Now, since the text follows the path of the circle, the text on the bottom half of the circle becomes upside down. How can this be fixed? I would like the text to be visible normally.

Any pointers on how this can be achieved is greatly appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The basic technique is that you need to have two paths, one for the top text, and one for the bottom.

1. Create a shape layer, and type on it, and position the text as required.
2. Duplicate the shape layer
3. Type on that, and position the text as required.
4. To get the text up the right way, click and drag it to the inside of the circle with the Direct Selection tool.
5. Highlight the text and change the baseline of the text in the Character panel to fit it to the outside of the circle.

[image: Example screenshot]